# I am trying to write a sql query for which crime is max in each district

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was asked to print the maximum crime along with the count that is taking place in each district which I have to write using only subqueries.

This is the the code that I tried:

```sql
select  DISTRICT, max(b) max_crime from
(select distinct count(offense_code_group)b,DISTRICT  from
 dbo.crime
group by DISTRICT,OFFENSE_CODE_GROUP)a
group by DISTRICT
;
```

By executing this, the output I got was this:
[image: output of the query after executing]

I need the name of the crime(offense_code_group) along with count.
Actual output:-
district   count    offense_code_group
A1        3496         Larceny

Comment: What is a "maximum crime"?

Comment: @Larnu thanks for responding but I got the count of maximum crime but need to get the name . for eg:- district A1 has larency as max crime i should get Larency also in the output along with its count

Comment: See the linked duplicate, which explains how to get the "top" row in each group.